# Remove spaces between columns in HighChart

Tags: highcharts

I have a little problem. I am ploting results vs. time, and the space between columns is very wide. The results arent uniform in the time.
[image: HighChart]

How can I remove this spaces?

Maybe there is an option to remove this space, but I dont know it

```
    $('#containerImc').highcharts({
    data: {
        table: document.getElementById('datatableImc')
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Lista de tus últimos IMC'
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: true,
        title: {
            text: 'IMC'
        }
    }
}
```

This is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sakyastelios/2kfo92t8/

Many thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the `type` of the `x-axis` to `category` by adding:

```
xAxis: {       
    type: 'category'
}
```

see also [this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2kfo92t8/1/).

x-axis values are not anymore handled as datetime objects and positioned accrodingly.